# Select a dummy column with a dummy value and search in dummy column in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two table which I need to join

```
Table1
col1   col2   col3 
------------------
 1      A      20 
 2      B      10
 3      C      30
 4      D      40

Table2
col1   col2
-----------
 1      A  
 2      B  
 3      C  
 4      D
```

I have to make UNION of both table. As **table2** doesn't have col3 I have added as dummmy column in query.

I need to perform search operation in both the table for **col3**

I tried but it throwing unknown column exception.

```
(SELECT col1, col2, col3 from table1 where col3 = "10")
 UNION
(SELECT col1, col2, "10" as col3 from table2 where col3 = "10")
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How can you search for col3 on table2 if it does not have such a column?

Comment: @juergend, after UNION operation we could search. I got my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the UNIONed data directly afterward:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 from
(
 (SELECT col1, col2, col3 from table1)
  UNION
 (SELECT col1, col2, "10" as col3 from table2)
) as b 
where col3 = "10"
```

Comment: I was expecting this one only. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a `WHERE` clause in Table2:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table1 WHERE col3 = '10'
UNION 
SELECT col1, col2, '10' FROM Table2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=840de809d37221089717603c4fd29231).
Results:

```
> col1 | col2 | col3
> ---: | :--- | :---
>    2 | B    | 10  
>    1 | A    | 10  
>    3 | C    | 10  
>    4 | D    | 10
```

Comment: `Where` clause is needed, as it can be any field value not specific to 10.

Comment: @Yash No the WHERE clause is needed only for Table1.